# dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Ambiguous project name

Tags: c#, azure-devops, .net-core-3.0

I'm currently trying to build an api and an azure webjob as a selfcontained .net core 3.0 app but during the build process i'm getting the following error no matter what configuration I try.

C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Ambiguous project name 'Grey-O-Tron'. [D:\a\1\s\Grey-O-Tron.sln]

This is the current build setup

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
variables:
  build.gittag: '6.6.1'
  build.number: '17'
  build.gitversion: '6.6.1+17'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 5.3.0'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.3.0

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .Net Core sdk 3.x'
  inputs:
    version: 3.x
    includePreviewVersions: true

- task: WouterVS.set-git-version-task.custom-build-release-task.Set git version@1
  displayName: 'Set Build''s Git Version'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'

- task: bleddynrichards.Assembly-Info-Task.Assembly-Info-NetCore.Assembly-Info-NetCore@2
  displayName: 'Set Assembly Manifest Data'
  inputs:
    InsertAttributes: true
    FileEncoding: 'utf-8'
    PackageId: 'Grey-O-Tron'
    Authors: 'Wouter Van Speybroeck'
    Company: woutervs
    Product: 'Grey-O-Tron'
    Copyright: 'Wouter Van Speybroeck'
    PackageProjectUrl: greyotron.eu
    RepositoryUrl: 'https://github.com/woutervs/Grey-O-Tron'
    VersionNumber: '$(build.gittag).$(build.number)'
    FileVersionNumber: '$(build.gittag).$(build.number)'
    InformationalVersion: '$(build.gitversion)'
    PackageVersion: '$(build.gitversion)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **\*.sln'
  inputs:
    platform: x86
    configuration: release
  enabled: false

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    arguments: '-c release -r win-x86'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'publish api'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/*Api.csproj'
    arguments: '--no-build -o $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) -c release -r win-x86 --self-contained true'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'publish bot'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/Grey-O-Tron.csproj'
    arguments: '--no-build -o $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\Grey-O-Tron -c release -r win-x86 --self-contained true'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'

pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
variables:
  build.gittag: '6.6.1'
  build.number: '17'
  build.gitversion: '6.6.1+17'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 5.3.0'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.3.0

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .Net Core sdk 3.x'
  inputs:
    version: 3.x
    includePreviewVersions: true

- task: WouterVS.set-git-version-task.custom-build-release-task.Set git version@1
  displayName: 'Set Build''s Git Version'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'

- task: bleddynrichards.Assembly-Info-Task.Assembly-Info-NetCore.Assembly-Info-NetCore@2
  displayName: 'Set Assembly Manifest Data'
  inputs:
    InsertAttributes: true
    FileEncoding: 'utf-8'
    PackageId: 'Grey-O-Tron'
    Authors: 'Wouter Van Speybroeck'
    Company: woutervs
    Product: 'Grey-O-Tron'
    Copyright: 'Wouter Van Speybroeck'
    PackageProjectUrl: greyotron.eu
    RepositoryUrl: 'https://github.com/woutervs/Grey-O-Tron'
    VersionNumber: '$(build.gittag).$(build.number)'
    FileVersionNumber: '$(build.gittag).$(build.number)'
    InformationalVersion: '$(build.gitversion)'
    PackageVersion: '$(build.gitversion)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **\*.sln'
  inputs:
    platform: x86
    configuration: release
  enabled: false

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    arguments: '-c release -r win-x86'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'publish api'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/*Api.csproj'
    arguments: '--no-build -o $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) -c release -r win-x86 --self-contained true'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'publish bot'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/Grey-O-Tron.csproj'
    arguments: '--no-build -o $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\Grey-O-Tron -c release -r win-x86 --self-contained true'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
```

Repo can be found at:
https://github.com/woutervs/Grey-O-Tron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that task **Set Assembly Manifest Data** sets the project id for your projects to a same value "Grey-O-Tron". Usually project id should be unique or blank for csproj.

You may need to omit the input **PackageId** for this task. I tested below yml, the build was successful without `PackageId`

```
- task: bleddynrichards.Assembly-Info-Task.Assembly-Info-NetCore.Assembly-Info-NetCore@2
  displayName: 'Set Assembly Manifest Data'
  inputs:
    InsertAttributes: true
    FileEncoding: 'utf-8'

    Authors: 'Wouter Van Speybroeck'
    Company: woutervs
    Product: 'Grey-O-Tron'
    Copyright: 'Wouter Van Speybroeck'
    PackageProjectUrl: greyotron.eu
    RepositoryUrl: 'https://github.com/woutervs/Grey-O-Tron'
    VersionNumber: '$(build.gittag).$(build.number)'
    FileVersionNumber: '$(build.gittag).$(build.number)'
    InformationalVersion: '$(build.gitversion)'
    PackageVersion: '$(build.gitversion)'
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I can't even remember why I would've set the package id as a static value... Tyvm!

Comment: Amazing, this solved it for me after a couple of days of pulling my hair out. I've had the  manifest data in the pipeline for ages, but only recently added dotnet build so assumed the old stuff wasn't the problem. Thank you!